# How to force Eclipse CDT to stop debugging and rebuild after source file edit&save

Tags: c, eclipse-cdt

How can I force Eclipse CDT to stop debugging and to rebuild the project after I edit & save the source file I am currently stepping through?

Or at least to stop debugging after I press Build Project. Currently, after I select Build Project, I get an error message `cannot open output file myapp.exe: Permission denied`. So I have to Terminate the app first, then do Build Project again. Happens all the time since I usualy edit the source and forget if I am in the debug mode or not.

Idealy, there would be a shortcut which would do Terminate+Build Project+Relaunch at one step.

Comment: That is a good idea, please file a [feature request](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT). Patches welcome.

Comment: Thanks. Submitted as Bug 510836: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=510836

Comment: Still nothing happening with feature request...

Comment: (reproduced from bug report) Hi Danijel - this bug is a great enhancement idea. I am willing to help you contribute it if you want to work on it. At the moment there is no one scheduled to work on it.

That said, using the Launchbar you can get some of this resolved. When you press the "Debug" or "Run" button on the launchbar it will terminate the existing session before starting a new one. Using that may help your flow in the meantime.